# My armatures from blender 2.7 was damaged on blender 2.8

Tags: animation, armature

After a hard work, I did a good armature's standard with all IK rules , constraints and restrictions for rotation, etc...

When I open my models on Blender 2.8 I 'have' more bones than 2.7 (like ik.neck_end) and my rules for all bones was lost.

Besides that, in blender 2.7 I recorded my animations in 10 frames, when I see the distribution of frames in Timeline everything is in 5 frames, why ?

Here a example of constrait lost :

[image: More bones why !?!]

[image: Constraint lost]

Comment: Another good example of why you should jump around versions with the same project

Comment: Try to append the complete contents of your "old" file into a freshly  started and emptied Blender 2.8 (no default cube, no default camera..."nothing". Good luck!

Comment: Ok, I'll try creating a totally empty file